# remove html input tag from string using C#

Tags: c#, html, regex

```
<pre>
    <p>The accounting equation asset = capital + liabilities, which of the following is true. Ram has started business with 5,50,000 and has purchased goods worth 1,50,000 on credit</p><p>
    <input type='radio' id='op1' name='q2option' value='1' /> a) 7,00,000 = 5,50,000 + 1,50,000 
    <input type='radio' id='op2' name='q2option' value='2' />b)7,00,000 = 6,50,000 + 50,000</p>
    <p> 
    <input type='radio' id='op3' name='q2option' value='3' /> c) 5,50,000 = 7,00,000 - 1,50,000 
    <input type='radio' id='op3' name='q2option' value='4' > d)5,50,000 = 5,00,000 + 50,000</p>
</pre>
```

I want to remove input tag in C#.Net for windows application 
I have changed the input tag stucture to show the code

Comment: Great. Go ahead. If you encounter problems, let us know.

Comment: Haven't got a clue what you are asking for here.......

Comment: If your string is always like this (assuming the input tags are well formed and your example has a typo), you could parse it and remove all strings between `<` and `>` included. You should look for `String.Substring()` and `String.IndexOf()` methods, thay will help you

Comment: I want to remove radio button from the html using c#.Net...

Comment: is there any regex to remove radio button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove input tags from the string with a regular expression:

```
var temp = "The accounting equation asset = capital + liabilities, which of the             following is true. Ram has started business with 5,50,000 and has purchased goods worth 1,50,000 on credit <input type='radio' id='op1' name='q2option' value='1' /> a) 7,00,000 = 5,50,000 + 1,50,000 <input type='radio' id='op2' name='q2option' value='2' />b)7,00,000 = 6,50,000 + 50,000 <input type='radio' id='op3' name='q2option' value='3' /> c) 5,50,000 = 7,00,000 - 1,50,000 <input type='radio' id='op3' name='q2option' value='4' /> d)5,50,000 = 5,00,000 + 50,000";

var regInput = new Regex("(.*?)(\\<input[^\\>]*\\>)(.*?)");

var result =regInput.Replace(temp,"$1$3");
```

Comment: Maybe try again, I changed the expression because it was not working if there were no line breaks between the input tags